# using array to determine score

Tags: php

Basically I wondering the best approach to determine a score based on a range defined in an array

I have a set of values ranging between 300 and 900 , each value has a corresponding percentile range.

I want to create a function that gives you the percentile based on the value checked. The value passed into the function may not match the defined value in the array, but want to return the highest percentile for that value.

For example in the array will be something like

```
'300'=>'10', '333'=>'11', '340' => '12'  .... '900'=>'100'
```

IF I pass in 335, then the function should return 11. Not sure simplest approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easly loop .. but if you don't want to do that then you can use

```
$var = 335 ;
$array = array('300'=>'10', '333'=>'11', '340' => '12');
echo getPercentage($array,$var);
```

Output

```
 11
```

Function Used

```
function getPercentage(array $a, $v) {
    if (array_key_exists($v, $a)) {
        return $a[$v];
    }
    $a[$v] = null;
    ksort($a);
    $pos = array_search($v, array_keys($a));
    $pos = array_slice($a, (($pos == 0) ? 1 : $pos - 1), 1);
    return reset($pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is ordered, it's straightforward.  If you start at the bottom (score = 300) then go up until your score is larger than the array score, and the correct percentile is the one you just passed on the way up.  If you start at the top, go down until your score is lower than the array score, and the correct percentile is the one you just passed on the way down.

Starting at the top or bottom of your array based on the score may give you a slight performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
<?php

function get_percentile($val){
    $arr = array('300'=>'10', '333'=>'11', '340'=>'12'); 
    while(!$arr[$val]){
        $val--;
    }
    return $arr[$val];
}

echo get_percentile(335);

?>
```

**Output:**
11

**[Check it out!](http://codepad.org/LGpSorAV)**